# Tailwind: modify classes dynamically for Vue app

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a Vue3 application with Tailwinds configured in tailwind.config.js

Is it possible to dynamically change the value of a preconfigured class from tailwind.config.js ?

For example:

---

**tailwind.config.js**:

```
const defaultTheme = require("tailwindcss/defaultTheme");

module.exports = {
  purge: ["./index.html", "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        base: {
          DEFAULT: "#6e0147",
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Interstate", "Inter var", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {
      ringWidth: ["hover", "active"],
      ringColor: ["hover", "active"],
      ringOpacity: ["hover", "active"],
      ringOffsetWidth: ["hover", "active"],
      ringOffsetColor: ["hover", "active"],
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

**VueComponent.vue** :

```
<template>
   <div class="text-base">text here</div>
</template>

<script>
   export default {
      .....

      mounted(){
         tailwind.config.colors.base = "#00000" // change tailwind color of class somehow
      }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: please share an example of what you want to achieve

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I've added example

Comment: do you want something like theming your app?

Comment: I need to change the base colors of certain elements dynamically based on configuration files. If that can be done via themes, then yes, but I don't know

Comment: as you did it's not possible, but you could achieve the theming process differently

Comment: How could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `tailwind.css` add a CSS variable called `--text-color-base` (you could add multiple) in the base theme and also in `theme-1`:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base{
  :root{
    --text-color-base:#6e0147;
  }

    .theme-1{
       --text-color-base:#000000;
     }
}
```

in   `tailwind.config.js` extend the textColor field in the theme option with skin key which will contain the different variable for your text color :

```
theme: {
    extend: {
      textColor:{
           skin:{
              base:"var(--text-color-base)"
            }
        },
      colors: {
        base: {
          DEFAULT: "#6e0147",
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ["Interstate", "Inter var", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
```

then you could use it like `class="text-skin-base"`, to apply the `theme-1` add the class `theme-1` to the root element like :

```
<div class="theme-1">
    <h1 class="text-skin-base">text here</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

then in your script you could bind the root class to a property and you update in the script :

```
<div :class="myTheme">
    <h1 class="text-skin-base">text here</h1>
    ...
</div>

<script>
   export default {
      .....
      data(){
        return{
          myTheme:''
        } 
       },
      mounted(){
         this.myTheme="theme-1"
      }
   }
</script>
```